# Android Programming(Shared Preferences)

Tags: java, android

I want to retrieve the username or email id which the user had provided in the login form using shared preferences.

Comment: Great.  What's the problem?  Google not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String username = prefs.getString("yourKey", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a `String` to `SharedPreferences`, use the following code:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    .edit().putString("username", username).commit();
```

To retrieve this value later on use the following code:

```
String username = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    .getString("username", "Default");
```